# PyAutoGUI - error caused by mouse on second monitor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have a program that uses PyAutoGUI to auto-sign me into work by opening programs, clicking things in timed order, etc. I set up a logging error text file and this morning it said the following: `ERROR:root:2023-04-06 08:00:03.184901 - PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.`

I went ahead and disabled this issue using `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False`. Question is, could this error be caused by my mouse being dormant on my second monitor when the program is triggered to run? The mouse doesn't slide, but instead uses moveTo to "teleport" to the coordinate I need it at.

I know the error gets raised when the mouse reaches the upper left corner (0,0), so is it possible the mouse teleporting from one screen to the other temporarily sets the mouse value as (0,0) thus causing the error?

Thanks,